# Конфигурация рамки окна

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

мне нужна помощь с тем чтобы "отключить" (просто убрать ее. Словно ее вообще не было)
кнопку "свернуть окно" в Windows
если есть возможность желательно чтобы отключалась она через tkinter

ВАЖНО:  я знаю про метод overrideredirect и toolwindow пожалуйста про него не пишите.

как это сделать даже близко не знаю.
есть некоторый код. Вот код:

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.geometry("500x300)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Попробуйте `window.attributes("-toolwindow", 1)`

Comment: @gord1402 спасибо за ответ но я забыл указать что это тоже не то что мне нужно. еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения Вашей проблемы нужно использовать библиотеку для доступа к низкоуровневым функциям Windows `ctypes`.

Это можно сделать следующим образлм:

```
import tkinter
from ctypes import windll

GWL_STYLE = -16
WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000


def disable_minimize_button(root):
    hwnd = windll.user32.GetParent(root.winfo_id())
    style = windll.user32.GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWL_STYLE)
    style = style & ~WS_MINIMIZEBOX
    windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style)


window = tkinter.Tk()
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.geometry("500x300")
window.update()
disable_minimize_button(window)

window.mainloop()
```

В функции `disable_minimize_button` я получаю текущий стиль окна, удаляю его (с кнопкой развернуть) и добавляю новый (без её).

Comment: спасибо, все работает примного благодарен

Comment: @Nove_Under889 рад слышать! Тогда отметьте ответ как правильный)

Comment: извини что ТАК поздно но все же твой ответ принят